# How to create a dynamic WHERE clause for all queries in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a requirement where I need to pass a global `WHERE` condition dynamically to all the queries?

We have data in the tables for multiple organizations. So, I need to pass `ORG_ID = ?` while retrieving data.

I don't want to write finder methods like `findBy..AndOrgId(... Integer orgId)`. Is there a better way to do this? To apply a Global `WHERE` clause or a Predicate?

I receive this `orgId` as part of the request attribute in `RestController`. Since it is dynamic, I can't use the hibernate annotation `@Where` on the entity classes.

Comment: @SternK Should not have removed the reference to spring data from the post

Comment: I did not do it. See [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). The post title is not appropriate please for the technology names.

Comment: @SternK Spring Data could be in the end of the title. Check an accepted answer assumption, for example.

Comment: Thanks.. I have added it to the end of the title

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64439512/1657465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data (I assume you are using Spring Data based on your post tags) doesn't support query augmentation (at time of writing).  There is a long standing request for that feature [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-293) that also describes some alternatives that others have tried.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.. yes was looking for a solution based on spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use hibernate `@Filter` annotation. As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter):

> The `@Filter` annotation is another way to filter out entities or collections using custom SQL criteria. Unlike the `@Where` annotation, `@Filter` allows you to parameterize the filter clause at runtime.

Example 1:

```java
import org.hibernate.annotations.Filter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ORDER")
@FilterDef(
   name="byId",
   parameters = @ParamDef(
      name="ordId",
      type="long"
   )
)
@Filter(
   name="byId",
   condition="ord_id = :ordId"
)
public class MyOrder
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ord_id")
   private Long id;

   // ...
}
```

and usage:

```java
EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
// ...
em.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("byId").setParameter("ordId", 2L);

List<MyOrder> orders = em.createQuery("select o from MyOrder o", MyOrder.class)
   .getResultList();
```

the following sql will be generated:

```sql
/* select o from MyOrder o */
select
  myorder0_.ord_id as ord_id1_3_,
  myorder0_.ord_time as ord_time2_3_ 
from TEST_SCHEMA.MY_ORDER myorder0_ 
where myorder0_.ord_id = ?
```

**EDIT**

The described above approach also works with spring data jpa `@Query` and the queries derived from the method names.

Example 2:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
@FilterDef(
   name="postById",
      parameters = @ParamDef(
         name="postId",
         type="long"
      )
   )
@Filter(
   name="postById",
   condition="id = :postId"
)
public class Post
{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   private PostStatus status;

   // getters, setters
}

public enum PostStatus { OPEN, CLOSE }

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long>
{
   @Query(value = "select p from Post p where p.status = :sts")
   List<Post> test(@Param("sts") PostStatus status);

   List<Post> findByStatus(PostStatus status);
}

@RestController
public class TestRestController
{
   @Autowired
   EntityManager entityManager;

   @Autowired
   private PostRepository postRepository;

   @RequestMapping("/")
   @Transactional
   public String home()
   {
      entityManager
          .unwrap(Session.class)
          .enableFilter("postById")
          .setParameter("postId", 10L);
       // ....
       List<Post> posts1 = postRepository.test(PostStatus.OPEN);
       List<Post> posts2 = postRepository.findByStatus(PostStatus.OPEN);
   }      
}
```

Comment: I liked the idea of using @Filter, is there any way to use in repository using `@Query` ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to load all the entities, mapping helped

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "is_active = true")
data class Account(
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    var phone: String,
    @Embedded
    val name: Name,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var password: String,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var role: Role,
    var isActive: Boolean
){
    @Id
    var id: Long = 0

    @CreationTimestamp
    var dateCreated: Timestamp? = null

    @UpdateTimestamp
    var dateUpdated: Timestamp? = null
}
```

Create the same entity and map it

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("select * from account")
data class AccountWithRemove(
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    var phone: String,
    @Embedded
    val name: Name,
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var password: String,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var role: Role,
    var isActive: Boolean,
    var code: Long?
) {
    @Id
    var id: Long = 0

    @CreationTimestamp
    var dateCreated: Timestamp? = null

    @UpdateTimestamp
    var dateUpdated: Timestamp? = null
}
```

This is how the request with the specification looks like. Search for regular and deleted accounts

```
from
        ( select
            * 
        from
            account ) accountwit0_ 
    where
        accountwit0_.is_active=true 
        or accountwit0_.is_active=false
```

And this is a normal findAll()

```
from
        ( select
            * 
        from
            account ) accountwit0_
```

Hibernate doesn't create a new table, we just create a new entity and map the one where we don't need the @Wnere annotation.
I removed some of the fields, but I think the meaning is clear