# Include additional columns in Where clause of Hibernate/JPA Generated UPDATE Query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, sharding

I am using Hibernate/JPA.

When i do an `entity.save()` or `session.update(entity)`, hibernate generates a query like this :-

```
update TABLE1 set COL_1=? , COL_2=? , COL_3=? where COL_PK=?
```

Can I include an additional column in the WHERE clause by means of any annotation in the entity, so it can result in a query like :-

```
update TABLE1 set COL_1=? , COL_2=? , COL_3=? where COL_PK=? **AND COL_3=?**
```

This is because our DB is sharded based on `COL_3` and this needs to be present in where clause

I want to be able to achieve this using the `session.update(entity)` or `entity.save()` only.

Comment: Are you using spring repositories?

Comment: @silentsudo yes i am using spring data JPA repositories

Comment: did you think about writing criteria query for this with addition to extar where clause you need, becuase save/update more or less works same in repository, overriding default save behaviour i will not suggest due to repository being used at different place and things might start to break

Comment: The table is huge with multiple columns and writing own query can be tedious and difficult to manage. Besides, this entity also has a @Version. With custom query, this will be difficult to manage manually.

Comment: Is the identifier of your entity only COL_PK or (COL_PK AND COL_3)? Things don't always work out as you wish man. I'd like many things to be done easily too but this is not one of them. You should select the entity depending on which condition you want, and then update the corresponding entity.

Comment: This demo application might give you ideas: https://github.com/ramsrib/multi-tenant-app-demo

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue @CarlssonEvert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand things correctly, essentially what you are describing is that you want hibernate to act like you have a composite primary key even though your database has a single-column primary key (where you also have a @Version column to perform optimistic locking).

Strictly speaking, there is no need for your hibernate model to match your db-schema exactly. You can define the entity to have a composite primary key, ensuring that all updates occur based on the combination of the two values. The drawback here is that your load operations are slightly more complicated.

Consider the following entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="test_entity", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})  })
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "col_3", nullable = false)
    private String col_3;

    @Column(name = "value", nullable = true)
    private String value;

    @Version
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer version;

    ... getters & setters

}
```

Then you can have the following method (in my case, I created a simple JUnit test)

```java
@Test
public void test() {

    TestEntity test = new TestEntity();
    test.setCol_3("col_3_value");
    test.setValue("first-value");

    session.persist(test);

    long id = test.getId();
    session.flush();
    session.clear();

    TestEntity loadedTest = (TestEntity) session
            .createCriteria(TestEntity.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
            .uniqueResult();

    loadedTest.setValue("new-value");
    session.saveOrUpdate(loadedTest);
    session.flush();

}
```

This generates the following SQL statements (enabled Hibernate logging)

```
Hibernate: 
    call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        test_entity
        (value, version, id, col_3) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.id as id1_402_0_,
        this_.col_3 as col_2_402_0_,
        this_.value as value3_402_0_,
        this_.version as version4_402_0_ 
    from
        test_entity this_ 
    where
        this_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        test_entity 
    set
        value=?,
        version=? 
    where
        id=? 
        and col_3=? 
        and version=?
```

This makes loading slightly more complicated as you can see - I used a criteria here, but it satisfies your criteria, that your update statements always include the column col_3 in the 'where' clause.

Comment: Seems reasonable enough. Two caveats to remember about, though: (1) not being able to use `Session.get()/EntityManager.find()` means every re-query for an already loaded entity will still hit the db, and (2) I think Hibernate will now expect you to use both columns as join columns for entity associations, meaning you now need an additional column for storing each to-one association (and also, some query plans might be adversely affected, I suppose)

Comment: Yes. If you have FK's to the tables, it will create problems.

Comment: I was able to do this using IdClass annotation. Is there a difference between using IdClass to define the primary key and the one you suggested?

Comment: also what do yyou mean by "load operations" being more complicated? what is the "load operation" ? is this the select statement ?

Comment: Using an IdClass is the same basic concept. The "load operation" is the "select" statement. If you use an IdClass or a composite primary key, then you cannot execute a "load-by-id" using the "current ID". You either need to use the id-class that you defined or else execute a query or select.

Answer (score 3):

The following solution works, however I recommend you to just wrap your `saveOrUpdate` method in a way that you ends up using a more natural approach. Mine is fine... but is a bit hacky.

### Solution:

You can [create your own annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation#1-class-level-annotation-example) and inject your extra condition to hibernate save method using a [hibernate interceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-interceptor). The steps are the following:

**1. Create a class level annotation:**

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ForcedCondition {
    String columnName() default "";
    String attributeName() default ""; // <-- this one is just in case your DB column differs from your attribute's name
}
```

**2. Annotate your entity specifying your column DB name and your entity attribute name**

```java
@ForcedCondition(columnName = "col_3", attributeName= "col_3")
@Entity
@Table(name="test_entity")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "col_3", nullable = false)
    private String col_3;

    public String getCol_3() {
        return col_3;
    }
    ... getters & setters

}
```

**3. Add a Hibernate interceptor and inject the extra condition:**

```java
public class ForcedConditionInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    private boolean forceCondition = false;
    private String columnName;
    private String attributeValue;

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(
            Object entity,
            Serializable id,
            Object[] state,
            String[] propertyNames,
            Type[] types) {
        // If your annotation is present, backup attribute name and value
        if (entity.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(ForcedCondition.class)) {
            // Turn on the flag, so later you'll inject the condition
            forceCondition = true;
            // Extract the values from the annotation
            columnName = entity.getClass().getAnnotation(ForcedCondition.class)).columnName();
            String attributeName = entity.getClass().getAnnotation(ForcedCondition.class)).attributeName();
            // Use Reflection to get the value 
            // org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils
            attributeValue = PropertyUtils.getProperty(entity, attributeName);
        }
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        if (forceCondition) {
            // inject your extra condition, for better performance try java.util.regex.Pattern
            sql = sql.replace(" where ", " where " + columnName + " = '" + attributeValue.replaceAll("'", "''") + "' AND ");
        }
        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
     }
}
```

After all that everytime you call `entity.save()` or `session.update(entity)` over an entity annotated with `@ForcedCondition`, the SQL will be injected with the extra condition you want.

**BTW:** I didn't tested this code but it should get you along the way. If I did any mistake please tell me so I can correct.