# Spring JPA fetch subset of OneToMany relation

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 Tables

- Articles
- Comments

```
@Entity(name = "articles")
data class Article(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long,

    @Column(name = "body")
    val body: String,

    @Column(name = "username")
    val username: String,

    @OneToMany
    val comments: List<Comment>,

    )
```

```
@Entity(name = "comments")
data class Comment(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long,

    @Column(name = "username")
    val username: String,

    @Column(name = "text")
    val text: String,

    )
```

and in the repository:

```
interface ArticlesRepository : JpaRepository<Article, Long>{
    
    fun findArticlesByUsername(username:String):List<Article>
}
```

*Code in Kotlin*

I'd like to get the list all articles and specific user comments only.

**What would be the best way to query the articles with the set of the comments made by query user (not all comments)?**

I found there is Hibernate `@Fetch` annotation (ex. `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)`) but not sure how  if it can be used or how to use it.

data example:

```
- article_a
  - comment_1 by user_x
  - comment_2 by user_z
- article_b
  - comment_1 by user_x
- article_c
```

I'd like to query the articles + comments by `user_z`
so the result would be:

```
- article_a
  - comment_2 by user_z
- article_b
- article_c
```

sorry im new to this and im trying to use the best practice to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Fetch` annotation will not help you as it's affect [fetching behavior](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetch-annotation) not filtering.

I guess you can try to use `@Filter` annotation here.

1. You can correct your mapping in the following way:

```java
@Entity(name = "articles")
data class Article(

    // ...

    @OneToMany
    @Filter(
       name="commentUser",
       condition="username = :name"
    )
    val comments: List<Comment>,

)
```

2. Then you can enable the filter:

```java
entityManager
    .unwrap( Session.class )
    .enableFilter("commentUser")
    .setParameter("name", "user_z");
```

3. And then call your `ArticlesRepository.findArticlesByUsername`  method.

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter) of the hibernate documentation.

P.S. I am not familiar with Kotlin, so the syntax may require correction.

Comment: is it possible to use the filter with `ArticlesRepository.findAll`? as `ArticlesRepository.findArticlesByUsername` will filter the articles by the username right now.

Comment: actually i couldn't manage to let the filter work using the repository, but it did work using `entityManager.createQuery("select a from articles a")`

Comment: Yes, the  filter should work for the `ArticlesRepository.findAll` as well as for the `ArticlesRepository.findArticlesByUsername` and more generally for all queries which use `Article` in the `from` clause. See as an additional example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63747718/6277104) answer.

Comment: thank you, what i found is it was missing `@Transactional`